# What is "0E-20"

Tags: testing, mbt

Im using a Model Based Testing tool (Conformiq).
It generates test cases with value "0" but when i export those test cases in java, the value written there is "0E-20" 
What does that mean? What is "0E-20" ?

the code is somwhat like this :

```
new CQRecordNumber(
            /** value */
            (float)0E-20));
```

Comment: It's E-notation: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation#E_notation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [this Wiki page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation#E_notation), `xEy` means `x * 10^y`, which, in your case, is `0 * 10^(-20)`

Comment: Oohhhh, its the scientific E notation. All this time i thought it has something to do with hex :P 

Thank you

Comment: Why would it use `(float)0E-20` instead of just `(float)0`?

Comment: That I don't understand myself